# I have this embed for leaderboards in my bot, but i would like it to create more than 1 embed, to show more than the first 10 in the list?

Tags: javascript, list, discord

```
exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

    let data = await cs.leaderboard(message.guild.id);
    if (data.length < 1) return message.reply("Nobody's in leaderboard yet.");

    const msg = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    
    let pos = 0;
    // This is to get First 10 Users )
    data.slice(0, 10).map(e => {
        if (!client.users.cache.get(e.userID)) return;
        pos++
        msg.setColor('#0099ff')
        msg.setTitle('Leaderboard')
        msg.setAuthor({ name: 'Arkbuddies UK', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/yHgaVv2.png', url: 'https://discord.js.org' })
        msg.setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/yHgaVv2.png')
        msg.addFields(
            { name: `${pos}\u200B\n`, value: `**${client.users.cache.get(e.userID).username}**`, inline: true },
        
            { name: `Wallet:`, value: `**${e.wallet}**  <:Wishbone:939942552809902150>'s`, inline: true },
            { name: `Bank:`, value: `**${e.bank}**  <:Wishbone:939942552809902150>'s`, inline: true},
        )
        msg.setTimestamp()
        msg.setFooter({ text: 'Arkbuddies UK', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/yHgaVv2.png' });
    });

    message.reply({
        embeds: [msg]
    }).catch();
}

exports.help = {
    name: "leaderboard",
    data: {
        name: 'leaderboard',
        description: "show's guild leaderboard.",
        options: []
    }
}

exports.conf = {
    aliases: ["lb"],
    cooldown: 5
}
```